# RemoveAt/ReplaceWith from multidimensional array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multidimensional-array

Here's what I was hoping to do:

```
Grid[elem.Column, elem.Row] = null;
```

but this code doesn't work like I would like.

I'm looking to remove the element from the Grid[,] and then have a null value replace it. Not to have the element there change to null since that element holds information that is still needed in the future.

Here's are chunks of my code since I believe I will be asked for more information.

```
public class GridController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Element Element;
    public Element[,] Grid;
    int _gridColumns = 40;
    int _gridRows = 40;

    void Start()
    {
        Grid = new Element[_gridRows, _gridColumns];

        for (int column = 0; column < _gridColumns; column++)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < _gridRows; row++)
            {
               Grid[column, row] = Instantiate(Element) as Element;
            }
        }
    }

    public void ChangeCell(Element elem, int newRow)
    {
        Grid[elem.Column, elem.Row] = null;
    }
}

public class Element : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GridController gridController;
    public int Column;
    public int Row;

    void OnMouseOver()
    {
        gridController.ChangeCell(this, Row);
    }
}
```

Be aware that there is more code but you should understand what I'm looking for with only that.

Here's basically what I would like though:

```
Grid[elem.Column, elem.Row].ReplaceWith(null);
```

but unfortunately I couldn't find anything of the sorts online.

Comment: Can you explain the distinction between "_I'm looking to remove the element from the Grid[,] and then have a null value replace it_" and "_Not to have the element there change to null_"?

Comment: I don't understand what you're looking for here. Can you please explain what you *want* instead of what you *don't want*? What behavior do you want?

Comment: `var obj = Grid[someIndex, someIndex2]; Grid[someIndex, someIndex2] = null;` is not what are you looking for? Now `obj` still have reference but in grid that place is `null`. Then you can save `obj` if you want.

Comment: I assume @Alox wants to keep the object itself, but have a nullreference in the grid. That would require the object to be saved somwhere else then, or store a reference somewhere else (for the garbage collector to not stop by).

Comment: Yes, as @CommodoreYournero says, I want the element to keep being that element but simply have a null value inside the multidimentional array. And since this is in C#, writing down Grid[x,y] = null is the same as element = null, or at least in my understanding it is. If not please correct me, I've only been coding in C# for half a year.

Comment: @Alox thats partly correct, but does not apply if you store the reference somewhere else like Roma's solution (i think). I find the pointer/ ref stuff is quite tricky in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by this way:

```
var obj = Grid[index1, index2]; // store reference in "obj"
Grid[index1, index2] = null; //replace object in Grid by "null"
```

So, now you have reference in `obj` variable and you can use it in your code (save, make some calculations or something else)

Comment: hmm, would it be of concern if the obj has a co-routine running?

Comment: Do you mean in a parallel situation? If that is the case you might want to lock the object..

Comment: @Alox, if you mean that it can have some influence on some work that this object do the answer is "No". You simply store reference in variable. In parrallel situation as "Blaatz0r" you can lock it.

Comment: Perfect, I wasn't too sure what was going to happen, thanks for the help! :)